# Is this the proper way of exiting from the application?

Tags: java, javafx, terminate

I have a JavaFX application that is working properly. I have created the application's GUI using Scene Builder and I managed to hook my controller. So, the application loads data from a database which is then displayed in an a `TableView`.

So the application is setup like this:

Controller: `StudenOverview.java`

```
    @Override
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {

    //SOMETHING IS MISSING HERE, WHAT IS IT?
    regNumber.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Student, String>("regNumber"));
    name.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Student, String>("firstName"));
    surname.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Student, String>("lastName"));
     buildData();
}

public void buildData() {
    BDConnect connection = new BDConnect();
    students = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    try {
        String loadDataSQL = "SELECT * FROM _students_ ORDER BY _id";
        ResultSet res = connection.connect().createStatement().executeQuery(loadDataSQL);
        while (res.next()) {
            Student st = new Student();
            st.setRegNumber(res.getString(1));
            st.setFirstName(res.getString(2));
            st.setLastName(res.getString(3));
            students.add(st);
        }
        table.setItems(students);
    } catch (SQLException | ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Could not load data, the system will exit!");
        //Of course i will print the error for debugging
        System.exit(-1);
        System.out.println("Could not laod data in the Table!");
    }
}
```

My `MainApp.java` class:

```
public class MainApp extends Application {

private Stage primaryStage;

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    this.primaryStage = primaryStage;
    this.primaryStage.setTitle("Student App");
    initRootLayout();

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

/**
 * Initializes the root layout.
 */
public void initRootLayout() {
    try {
        // Load root layout from fxml file.
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        loader.setLocation(MainApp.class.getResource("view/StudentOverview.fxml"));
        // Show the scene containing the layout.
        Scene scene = new Scene(loader.load());
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Every thing is working fine but my concern is when the `buildData`method fails to load data, say due to an SQL syntax, the application will display an empty table in the GUI. This is `bad` because the user will not be able to work with the application without data in the table. So, in my case I have used `System.exit()` to exit from the application.

**So, my questions:**

Is this the proper way of doing it? What do you programmers recommend? How would you do it if where you?

Comment: You should at least use the `Application.stop` method at some point to ensure your resources are gracefully closed. See the section about the life-cycle of a JavaFX application at https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/application/Application.html

Comment: @AustinD Where should I call that method? In my Controller class?

Comment: When you close the application (e.g. by clicking the X button on the window) the `stop` method is automatically called.

Comment: @AustinD Yes, that is fine but I am asking in my case because the application must not continue to execute if it fails to load data

Comment: the int parameter of the exit method indicates an error if not 0, I think -1 is not a correct value, see standard http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799//utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_08_02

Comment: @Jay But is not that the catch block is executed when an error occurs? Will not that require an argument `-1`?

Comment: if one of SQLException | ClassNotFoundException is thrown by any lines in the *try* block then the *catch* block lines would be executed. In such case, the last line of the application would be the *exit*. It is possible to register hooks to be executed on a System.exit(...) I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

System.exit() is a force exit, you may use this:

```java
Platform.exit();
```

Comment: My question is:  Is it the proper way of exiting from the application? Like is it fine that I exit the system in the catch block?

Comment: Should I call that method in place of `System.exit()`? What cost does one method have over the other?

Comment: I see, sorry that I misunderstood your question.But when the exception was caught (SQLException or ClassNotFoundException), it is also considered as a critical error which the application should not continue to run.

Comment: Well, Platform.exit() is like to exit gracefully whereas System.exit() is to exit immediately?

Comment: So that means `System.exit()` is fine in that case?

Comment: It does not wrong. But when you want to shutdown your computer, will you switch off the power direct or to click the Shutdown button?

Comment: :D when the machine is not responding I go for power direct

Comment: @Giovanrich from the [JavaFX Application javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Application.html): "Calling [Platform.exit()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Platform.html#exit--) is the preferred way to explicitly terminate a JavaFX Application. Directly calling System.exit(int) is an acceptable alternative, but doesn't allow the Application stop() method to run.".

Comment: @jewelsea Thanks for explaining it to me.